# UIwebview Check whether the webpage exists

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview in my app .I will enter url in to the webview through a UITextfield continuosly . I need to check whether the webpage exists on the url each time url is passed clicking on the webobjects also forward me to new page there also I need to check the web page exists or not .please help me on this

Comment: Set `UIWebView` delegate and add delegate method `-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error`. This method will call whenever url not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can it by using NSData as follows;

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if (data.length==0) {
    NSLog(@"webpage does not exists");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"webpage exists");
}
```